# Extracting year from a masked array - python

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, masked-array

I have masked array from which I extracted and converted Datetime from a time series presented in terms of **seconds from start date** into an 'Array of an object'. Using the following in python.

`date=num2date(time, units = data.variables['time'].units)`

when I print date I get

```
Out[41]: 
masked_array(data=[cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2002, 8, 23, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2003, 9, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2004, 12, 24, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2005, 6, 18, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2006, 9, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2007, 9, 19, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2008, 3, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2009, 8, 16, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2010, 11, 21, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2011, 11, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2012, 2, 27, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2013, 6, 29, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2014, 6, 15, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2015, 3, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2016, 1, 10, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2017, 7, 25, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2018, 1, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2019, 1, 26, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2020, 12, 23, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False),
                   cftime.DatetimeGregorian(2021, 4, 30, 9, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=False)],
             mask=False,
       fill_value='?',
            dtype=object)
```

Now what I want is to extract from this is the year and separately the month.  How would I go about doing this given it is a masked array?

Answer (score 0):

`date[0].year` will return the first year
`date[0].month` will return the first month